# How do I close unwanted windows?

Tags: interface

[image]

The top two tabs won't close. I've tried and can't seem to find out how to get rid of them on my own.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way. You must have all margin lines aligned to be able to close your top tabs. For example, Img 1 will close, but Img 2 and Img 3 won't.

*Img 1:*

[image]

*Img 2 & 3:*

[image] [image]

To close your windows, collapse the top *Info* bar to the left by grabbing and dragging the hashmarks at the bottom-left, to the left. Then, grab the hashmarks at the top right of the bottom *Info* bar and drag upwards. Lastly, grab the divide line between the top of the *3D Viewport*/*Outliner* and drag it upward to condense the *Info* bar.

[image]