# How do I achieve the tri view in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

How do I achieve this view in blender??
I've tried quad view but it's not the same effect.
I want to be able to assign different backgrounds for each view separately as Im using it to make a car model.'
Thank you.

[image]

EDIT: ok I found out how to do it, you get to any corner of any view and you just drag it. and then from view , you change it to whatever ortho you want.
Now how do I delete one of them if I made one by mistake?

Comment: have a look here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21008/can-not-close-windows-in-interface/21012#21012 and the included link here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the three hash marks in the top right corner of the *3D Viewport* and drag to the left to divide the view. <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the three hash marks in the top right corner of the right *3D Viewport* and drag downward to divide the view again. You can now add a different *Background Image* to each.

*Tri View:*

[image]

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: thank you!
How do I delete one If I created it by mistake?

Comment: Grab the three hash marks and drag onto the one that you want to close. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53644/how-do-i-close-unwanted-windows